# Switching to Zsh in macOS Catalina not working

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, macos-catalina

I decided to take the plunge and switch to `zsh`. So, I followed the Terminal window instructions and entered:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

I then entered `echo $0`to see the switch - and it returned `-bash`!

Then, I went to the [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050), and followed the instructions there to make the change through System Preferences. However, the "Login shell" dropdown already showed `zsh`:

[image: Login shell dropdown showing <code>zsh</code>]

So, I thought maybe I need to reboot... Nope, the System Preferences still show `zsh`, Terminal returns `-bash`, and when I try to re-run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`, Terminal returns `chsh: no changes made`.

Running `echo $SHELL` in Terminal returns `/bin/zsh`.

What am I missing???

Comment: Close your terminal windows and open another.

Comment: Maybe your terminal emulator can be configured separately which shell to use...

Comment: Have closed and re-opened Terminal completely, opened a new tab, and opened a new window, @lx07, and rebooted - still the Terminal is using `bash`.

Comment: I checked Terminal's Preferences, also, to ensure no startup run command is present, @mpy. The line is blank.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay - one more place to check:

In Terminal's Preferences, under the General pane, there's an option to use the default login shell or set another. For some reason, mine is set to use another (probably set this in a far away time and place for some long done learning opportunity, lol).

[image: Preferences, General Pane, shows I have <code>bash</code> entered, rather than Default login shell selected...]

Selected "Default login shell", opened a new Terminal window, and voilà, all is working as expected! Sheesh...

Found to look there in the [same support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050), under "How to use a different shell without changing the default".

Comment: Nice self-solved question!

Answer (score 0):

A hard reset from *Shell -> Hard Reset* will do the job.

Comment: This may help in some circumstances; however, it doesn’t set the Terminal back to default settings. So, if the command path is set to something else, as mine was, this wouldn’t have helped. Again, it may help in other situations, so others may find this answer helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I repeated running "chsh -s /bin/zsh" from ssh terminal to my Big Sur then exit for a couple of times. Since the 2nd time it started to echo "no changes made". It seems until I logged into Big Sur from macOS UI with the same user account then the shell started to prompt zsh from ssh terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Try entering the terminal preferences with command key + enter before changing the changing it.

Comment: Can you give more information, @user1194882? It's not clear what you mean or how this would fix the problem. Please clarify...